# Python list of lists as a dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists like the following:

```
servers = [['serv1','10.10.10.10','00','onehost'],['serv2','10.10.10.20','01','twohost']]
```

I need a dictionary such as the following

```
Appdict = {'App': ['serv1','10.10.10.10','00','onehost'],['serv2','10.10.10.20','01','twohost']}
```

I've tried the zip method by zipping 2 lists but there are difficulties parsing the data in the front end. 
I've also tried the below:

```
for i in servers:
   Appdict.update(servers[i])
```

What would be the best way to create the dictionary? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure that you do not miss a second key for server2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want this:

```
Appdict  = {}
Appdict['App'] = servers
```

This will produce:

```
In [2723]: Appdict
Out[2723]: 
{'App': [['serv1', '10.10.10.10', '00', 'onehost'],
  ['serv2', '10.10.10.20', '01', 'twohost']]}
```